# lockf.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gdb, glibc

Please see the UPDATE at the botton of this post for more info.

Below is the _pqos_api_lock program from cap.c from the Intel CMT-CAT distribution (cache management technology - cache allocation technology) at https://github.com/intel/intel-cmt-cat.

The function _pqos_api_lock calls lockf, which is defined in unistd.h, and unistd.h is included with the includes at the top of the file.  However, debugging with gdb, I get "lockf.c: No such file or directory" at the line:

```
if (lockf(m_apilock, F_LOCK, 0) != 0)
          err = 1;
```

Going back to the command line, "locate lockf.c" and "find lockf.c brings up:

```
find: ‘lockf.c’: No such file or directory
```

I have unistd.h included, so why do I get this error?  I found source for lockf.c at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/io/lockf.c.html -- perhaps I can link this into my executable, although that sounds like a kludge.

Here is the source code for _pqos_api_lock:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
[ other includes omitted ]

void _pqos_api_lock(void)
{
        int err = 0;

        if (lockf(m_apilock, F_LOCK, 0) != 0)
                err = 1;

        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&m_apilock_mutex) != 0)
                err = 1;

        if (err)
                LOG_ERROR("API lock error!\n");
}
```

The full source code for cap.c is 1,722 lines long, so I did not include all of it here, but it's available at the github link above -- if needed, please ask and I'll post it all.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and I compiled with Clang.

Thanks for any ideas.

UPDATE:

In his answer below, Employed Russian shows that the "cannot find source lockf.c" is a gdb message stating that it has no access to lockf.c.  However, error is now here:

```
void _pqos_api_lock(void)
{
        int err = 0;

        if (lockf(m_apilock, F_LOCK, 0) != 0)
                err = 1;

        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&m_apilock_mutex) != 0)
                err = 1;

        if (err)
                LOG_ERROR("API lock error!\n");
}
```

The line "if (lockf(m_apilock, F_LOCK, 0) != 0)" fails because according to gdb:

p (int) F_LOCK
No symbol "F_LOCK" in current context.

That looks like an error in the program distributed by Intel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have unistd.h included, so why do I get this error?

You don't seem to understand the significance of this error (which is *none*). This error is safe to ignore, and doesn't affect your program's execution in *any way*.

The reason GDB displays this error is that GDB can't show you the source (because GDB doesn't know where that source is).

Chances are, you don't actually *want* to see this source at all.

> I found source for lockf.c at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/io/lockf.c.html

Good. If you really want to see what `locf` does, you can look there.

> perhaps I can link this into my executable

The *function* defined in `lockf.c` is *already* linked into your executable (you'd get a link error if it wasn't). You can't link source into your executable any more than you can link your kitchen sink into it.

What you can do is *install* `libc6-dbg` package, which includes source for *all* of GLIBC, *and* allows GDB to find the sources *automatically*.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that it's a gdb error (does not have the source file).  But the error I get now is:  "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff78f07c8 in lockf (fd=4, cmd=1, len=0) at lockf.c:39
39      lockf.c: No such file or directory."

Comment: So it finds an error at line 39 of a non-existent file.

Comment: "You can't link source into your executable" -- not entirely true.  Compile a .c file to a .o file, then link the .o file into your final executable.  I do that with other C programs linked into my nasm source.  However, as you point out, it's not necessary here and doesn't help.

Comment: @RTC222 "That looks like an error in the program distributed by Intel." -- no, it doesn't. It looks like you don't understand how macros work. If you need help understanding the `SIGSEGV`, ask a different question with segmentation-fault tag, and provide complete output from GDB `where` and `info registers`  commands.